# Graphing Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, analysis, multivariable-calculus, quadratic-forms

Recently I've been studying quadratic forms $p^TBp$ algebraically, but I would like to be able to visualize them (the ones from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ of course). I have done some experiments for myself using the online grapher [math3d](https://www.math3d.org/), but I don't know if I captured all the possibilities.

- Positive definite quadratic forms seem to be upward-opening parabolas rotated around the line $\{(0, 0, z)|z \in \mathbb{R} \}$, which are then streched or shrinked along the $x$ and $y$ axes (not sure if along other directions as well)

Ex:
$$\textbf{x}^T
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\textbf{x} = 
x^2+2xy+4y^2$$
[image]

- Positive semidefinite quadratic forms seem to be rotated and streched versions of the graph of $f(x, y) = x^2.$

Ex: 
$$\textbf{x}^T \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2\\
2 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \textbf{x} = x^2+4xy+4y^2$$

[image]

- Negative definite and semifinite forms are just negatives of positive definite and semidefinite forms.
- Indefinite quadratic forms seem to be all saddles.

Ex:$$
\textbf{x}^T \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 3\\
3 & 4
\end{bmatrix} \textbf{x}^T= x^2+6xy+4y^2
$$

[image]

- I know it's only worth looking at quadratic form with symmetric matrices, since for any matrix $A$ there exists a symmetric matrix $B$ such that $\forall v: v^TAv = v^TBv$

My question is, did I capture all the possibilities? Is there anything else helpful, or other "common knowledge", that I should know about the graphs of quadratic forms?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You also have the zero quadratic form whose graph is just the $xy$ plane. Other than that, you have captured all possibilities: A standard result in the theory of quadratic forms is that any quadratic form is equivalent up to a linear change of variables to $x^2 + y^2,-x^2 -y^2, x^2 - y^2, x^2, 0$ so it's not surprising to find the graphs you described. Alternatively, any quadratic form is equivalent up to an orthogonal change of variables (rotation/rotation+reflection) to $ax^2 + by^2$ so they look up to a rotation/reflection like the standard stretched paraboloid or other cases you describe.

Comment: @levap Thanks for the comment! So, to expand the argument in more detail, I guess I $kind of$ see why the graph of $f(2x, 3y)$ would be a shrunken version of the graph of $f(x, y)$; so if the graph of $f(2x, 3y)$ is like one of the $5$ types you mentioned, then stretching it back to the graph of $f(x, y)$ won't change its type. But I don't have the geometric intuition to tell what kind of effect a transformation like $(x, y) \mapsto (2x-3y, 5x+2y)$ has.